# how to hide cmd window while working with window tools in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, os.system

I am copying some files in my program. but I find out to increase copying speed, we can also use window tools such as 'xcopy'. my instruction is written below.

```
os.system('xcopy "%s" "%s" %(src,dst))
```

I am wondering, is it possible to hide cmd window. because it is keep appearing every time, I am iterating through for loop. 
my program is looking like,

```
for k in list1:
   if k in list2.keys():
      os.system('xcopy "%s" "%s" %(x\y\z + k, list2[k]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I came up with a better solution of my own program.
I have replace

```
os.system('xcopy "%s" "%s" %(x\y\z + k, list2[k]))
subprocess.Popen('xcopy /y ' src + ' ' + dst,creationflags = 0x08000000)
```

"creationflags = 0x08000000" can hide the cmd window. with Popen, it will not wait for the copy to finish. so we can copy multiple files together.